# Firefox Add-on Icon No Longer Showing Following Firefox 29 Update

Tags: javascript, firefox

Prior to the FF v29 update, my add-on was working as expected. Namely, the icon appeared in the customize menu such that users could drag it to wherever in the UI they wished.

However, **after the v29 update, the icon no longer appears in the "Additional Tools and Features" customization menu**.

The exact implementation in overlay.xul is as follows:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="trafficcodex-button" class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional" label="Traffic Codex Promo Code Finder" tooltiptext="Check for Promo Codes!" oncommand="trafficcodexpromocodefinder.overlay.search();" />
</toolbarpalette>

<window id="main-window">
    <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
        <toolbar id="trafficcodex-toolbar" toolbarname="Traffic Codex Promo Code Finder" accesskey="T" customizable="true" mode="icons" context="toolbar-context-menu" defaultset="trafficcodex-button" insertbefore="PersonalToolbar" />
    </toolbox>
</window>
```

Also of note is that this is **not** a bootstrapped extension.

This is the first browser extension I've ever developed, and I admittedly don't know much in this regard.

Comment: Is your addon still loaded? Often addons are disabled after a Firefox update because they are (possibly) incompatible with the new version.

Comment: @Stijn - Initially, it was still loaded, and the icon was still viewable. However, new users of the extension notified me that upon installing the extension, the icon did not show up. I reset Firefox and discovered this to be true for me as well.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the mean time? Facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but a link to the docs

[Firefox 29 changes - for developers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/29#Changes_for_add-on_and_Mozilla_developers) → [Australis and add-on compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Australis_add-on_compat) - "This is a major Firefox theme change that affects most extensions that involving the Firefox user interface."